# Is it necessary, and if so, where can I add Time.deltaTime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add Time.deltaTime somewhere, but I can't quite figure out where. Everything works as it is, but to ensure equal movement between all computers and fps, Time.deltaTime seems necessary.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //================= MOVEMENT =====================
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 movePosition;

    //Aiming
    public Camera cam;
    Vector2 mousePos;

    // Update is called once per frame: Good for INPUTS
    void Update()
    {
        //movement
        float moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float moveY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        movePosition = new Vector2(moveX, moveY).normalized;

        //aiming
        mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }
    // Called Set amount of times. Good for PHYSICS CALCULATIONS
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();

        //aim
        Vector2 lookDirection = mousePos - rb.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDirection.y, lookDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        rb.rotation = angle;
    }

    void Move()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(movePosition.x * moveSpeed, movePosition.y * moveSpeed) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr -> **You don't need it!** Look at the bottom of this answer

---

[`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) is the time passed since the last frame was rendered.

=> for e.g. 60 F/S this value will be around `0.017` => you need 60 of it in order to reach a factor of `1`.

So in short by multiplying a value with [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) it converts it from `value per frame` into `value per second`.

---

> Is it necessary

Depends on your use-case ... do you want a fix value per frame (frame-rate dependent) or do you rather want a value per second (frame-rate independent).

Of course there are things you want to do on a per frame base like e.g. interpolating position inputs from an eye-tracker in order to stabilize the input but in general frame-rate dependent is usually a bad thing.

For something like

```
transform.position += transform.forward * moveSpeed;
```

it means

- If you have a more powerful device => more frames can be rendered in the same time => You move faster
- If you have a slow device => less frames can be rendered in the same time => You move slower

---

> where can I add Time.deltaTime

Well, it is a `float` so you can add it wherever you want and can multiply something by a `float` ;)

In your specific use-case: **YOU DON'T**. The [`Rigidbody.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

```
rb.velocity = movePosition * moveSpeed;
```

already **is** an **absolute** velocity in **Unity units per seconds**, so there is no need to multiply by `Time.deltaTime` for this!

Just as a counter example a use-case where you **would** need it would be using this instead

```
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movePosition * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Using the same code, how can I add acceleration?
I've tried a bunch of different methods, but my lack of knowledge and practical skills are making me stuck.